# zsh plugin for fish-like auto suggestions for files and directories in present working directory

Tags: linux, plug-in, arch-linux

Looking for a zsh plugin for giving me suggestions for files and directories in the present working directory just like zsh-autosuggestions plugin provide suggestions by looking at history.

Consider following directories in my pwd:

```
 #  ls
    Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music
```

If I type "cd Dow" then I should get fish-like suggestions for "cd Downloads" as there is only one directory that starts with "Dow".